# getting multiple form values with the same name (bool case)

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

In an MVC Action how can I access values from "form data" submitted with multiple values for the same name?

**What i have done**: 
values of type int, decimal, string are working perfect.

**Problem**: there is a checkbox for each variant so when I try to get that it shows simply null in action rather than other values shows e.g (string length 2 and then values in it)

[Image of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoNEy.png)

You can see in the form other fields submit perfectly. But those **Use Coupon** checkbox is not working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple values submitted to one variable then as you can assume this variable must be collection to handle data. Just do some model that will be your checkbox and then pass list of it to the one that is used for this certain view.

Short example:

```
public class Checkbox
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool Required { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public bool Disabled { get; set; }
}

public class SimpleViewModelForCoupons
{
   public List<Checkbox> Coupons { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: that didn't help. :(

Comment: Oh are you adding new variants via JS? If yes then when you are generating new checkbox field you must specify its name and id. Would be good to have more information about it.